# ошибка Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'member' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пишу дискорд бота который по команде создает приватный текстовый канал, куда через отметку можно будет добавлять пользователя в доступ к каналу, но выдача прав на канал через отметку не работает.

скрипт:

```
@bot.command(name = "private")
async def private(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete(delay = 15)
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id = 925343467637444619) #категория
        if ctx.channel.id == 925365300814303232:
            emb = (discord.Embed(title = f"создан временный приватный канал.", color = discord.Color.red()))
            emb.add_field(name = "канал удалится через 3 минуты.", value = "разрешенный пользователь:{} ".format(member.mention))
            await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after = 30) #вывод сообщения
            
            overwrites = {
                ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, manage_channels = True), #настройки канала
                ctx.member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, manage_channels = True)
            }   #здесь ⬆️ ошибка Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'member'
            
            channel_tp = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name = "╎╎", overwrites = overwrites, category = maincategory) #создание канала
            time.sleep(180)
            await channel_tp.delete()
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"временный приватный канал удален.", color = discord.Color.red()), delete_after = 10) #удаление канала
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context — среди разрешённых атрибутов класса `Context` нет `member`.

Comment: а как тогда сделать

Comment: думаю, нужно просто убрать `ctx.` из кода: `member: discord.PermissionOverwrite...`

Comment: заработало спасибо